# Can't create a database with Odoo: Database creation error: OperationalError()

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to create my first database here, but I get this error:(error image)

[image: 1]

I also checked the log and this is what I found:

```
022-08-14 23:10:15,799 6576 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
2022-08-14 23:10:15,839 6576 INFO None odoo.service.db: Create database `odoo_db`. 
2022-08-14 23:10:15,874 6576 INFO None odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
2022-08-14 23:10:15,875 6576 ERROR None odoo.http:  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 141, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 462, in dispatch
    return g[exp_method_name](*params)
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in exp_create_database
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 41, in if_db_mgt_enabled
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 130, in exp_create_database
    _create_empty_database(db_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 99, in _create_empty_database
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 709, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 259, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 592, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 660, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\python\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
2022-08-14 23:10:15,939 6576 INFO None odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
2022-08-14 23:10:15,964 6576 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2022 23:10:15] "POST /web/database/create HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0 0.000 5.881
2022-08-14 23:10:16,162 6576 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
2022-08-14 23:10:16,165 6576 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2022 23:10:16] "GET /web/database/Roboto-Regular.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 - 0 0.000 0.047
```

Comment: How do you host your app? Do you use docker or bare metal? Odoo cannot access database.